# Prestashop - media files don't load (403 error)

Tags: php, prestashop, http-status-code-403

I'm currently learning Prestashop. I ran into first obstacle, after installing Prestashop, the default shop theme files don't load. Any ideas?

[image: 403 error when trying to get css files]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've already found solution for my question.

It turns out that my server provider doesn't support **FilesMatch** .htaccess command. In order to solve it i had to change .htaccess file in both /themes and /modules directory as follows:

```
 <FilesMatch "\.tpl$">
 Deny from all
 </FilesMatch>
```

to:

```
 <Files ~ "\.tpl$">
 Deny from all
 </Files>
```